# TreeMap is missing a key from the Object Rows

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using the Apache POI library to read values from an Excel sheet into a Java program.

I iterate through each row of a table to get the values I need.

Within the object Row, there is a TreeMap that contains XSSFCell objects as values.

Normally I get the following TreeMap:

[image]

Where **key 4** is included. The value often is an empty string as chosen in this picture.

For some reason, for some objects I get the following TreeMap:

[image]

Where the **key 4** is missing.

Both Row Objects belong to the same table.

This is how I use my object Row:

```
 XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheet("nameOfSheet");
 Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();

 while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        // here I call my method
    }
```

Comment: In an `Excel` file not all possible cells and rows are always stored. Else each `*.xlsx` `Excel` file would must have all 1,048,576 rows having 16,384 cells stored. Cells which do not have content or formatting are not stored. Those not stored cells, the iterator will not have and also the internal `_cells` map will not contain. See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator.

Comment: Your explanation sounds reasonable. I do not understand though, why for some of the cells that are in the same state (format and content) but in different rows, the Row object reacts differently. I think I'll just use a try/catch to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this from causing inconsistency in your application by calling "getCell()" passing in both an index and a [MissingCellPolicy](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html), probably Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL.

The [Apache POI guide](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) explains:

> In some cases, when iterating, you need full control over how missing
>   or blank rows and cells are treated, and you need to ensure you visit
>   every cell and not just those defined in the file. (The CellIterator
>   will only return the cells defined in the file, which is largely those
>   with values or stylings, but it depends on Excel).
>
> In cases such as these, you should fetch the first and last column
>   information for a row, then call getCell(int, MissingCellPolicy) to
>   fetch the cell. Use a MissingCellPolicy to control how blank or null
>   cells are handled.

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
   if (r == null) {
      // This whole row is empty
      // Handle it as needed
      continue;
   }

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```